# Most efficient/appropriate way to to enunciate a web form in Html5

Tags: html

Would something like this be (list style for example) correct in HTML5? What is the most recommended way to put a web form into HTML5? Thanks guys.

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="form2">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required placeholder="Rosa de Benito">
        </li>       
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Argüelles@hotmail.com"/>
        </li>   
        <li>
            <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label>
            <input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" required placeholder="669 669 669">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="website">Website:</label>
            <input type="url" name="website" id="website" required placeholder="http//www.ciñatiesa.com">
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: If you look around at the many examples on the internet (and, presumably, in your book) they use fieldsets, tables or divs, generally. Is there a particular reason you see the questions as list-items? Also note that your last li is unclosed. But this really isn't a suitable question for stackoverflow.

Comment: This question doesn't show the necessary research effort to be  answerable. You should review [the html5 form documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html) and [the results of validating your code](https://validator.w3.org/) and ask specific questions.